# Spring Webservice @Autowired suddenly not work in Java 8

Tags: spring, java-8, autowired

We have Spring (3.0.6) `@WebSerice` working fine with `@Autowried` to `@Service` and `@Repository` with Java 7.

Recently, we need to upgrade to Java 8 then the repository class can not `@Autowired`.

Very simple Resposity:

> ```
> @Repository
> public interface MyClss extends JpaRepository<MyData, String> {
>     MyData findOne( String key );
> }
> ```

Is there any difference in `@Autowrited` from Java 7 to Java 8 in Spring?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Ah sorry, i foget the error :
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type ...
 found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}....

Comment: But something weird, We enable Jrebel on my local develop server Tomcat, It work with Java 8.

Comment: It might be because of the fact that your Context is unable to load properly and thus Spring is not able to initialize any Beans. It is one of the most common error I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

I think `@Repository` is only for use on classes, not interfaces.  If this is a Spring 3 app, you must either compile the code as java 7 or upgrade to Spring 4.  See [spring-core 3.2.9 + java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657418/spring-core-3-2-9-java-8)

Comment: Thanks you, we fixed it by get the service by ApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

Because our legacy project very old containing many old lib and packages, we can not upgrade to Spring 4 or upper 3.2.

We fixed the problem, when figure out that the top lever are using CXF Webservice ( 2.x ). That CXF version not support Java 8.

[Spring bean not injected into CXF web service, Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456119/spring-bean-not-injected-into-cxf-web-service-why)

So, instead of using @Autowired, we change to get the Service Class with @Repository by ApplicationContext, It's work.

Ex:
OrderService orderService = applicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(OrderService.class);