# Jersey Restful web service don't call an Hibernate method

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, maven, jersey

I want to create a restful webservice using jersey. I have an existed project made by spring+maven+hibernate. And I want to use the Hibernate’s CRUD methods to make my web service.

here is the code of my service class:

```
@Component
public class MotServices {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
@Transactional
public Mot getMotByNom(String nom) {
    Mot mot = new Mot();
    // Acquire session
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        String queryString = "from Mot where nom = :nom";
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setString("nom", nom);
        mot = (Mot) query.uniqueResult();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println(mot);
    return mot;
}
}
```

and here is the code for my webservice:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWS {


@Resource(name="motservices")
private MotServices motservices;

Mot mot = new Mot();


public MotServices getMotservices() {
    return motservices;
}

public void setMotservices(MotServices motservices) {
    this.motservices = motservices;
}

public Mot getMot()
{
    return mot;
}

public void setMot(Mot mot) {
    this.mot = mot;
}
@GET
@Path("/Mot1/mot/{param}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Mot getMot(@PathParam("param") String param) {
    try{
         mot = motservices.getMotByNom(param);
    //  mot = motservices.Recherccher("Arbeit", "");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
         mot = new Mot("motAAAA","motBBBB", "motCCCC");         
    }
    return mot;
}
}
```

but the result when i call the webservice through this link 
"http://localhost:8080/Worterbuch/rest/hello/Mot1/mot/Arbeit"
i have only a null value; the result its like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<mot>
<definition>motBBBB</definition> 
<example>motCCCC</example>
<id>0</id>
<nom>motAAAA</nom>
</mot>
```

have you any Idea ?

here is the applicationcontext-web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- This file contains all the imports to other Spring application context 
    files. -->
<import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml" />


<context:annotation-config />

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.zied.langue.controllers,   com.zied.langue.WS" />



  </beans>
```

Comment: Post the spring config file!  Seems like your `motservices` is not getting injected and throwing `NullPointerException`

Comment: Is the issue that only the <id> has value 0 or null or the entire response object itself is null. Any exceptions like NoSuchBeanDefinitionException , Please update

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions in this post and finally i fixed the problem. thank you.

[Spring bean not injected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456119/spring-bean-not-injected-into-cxf-web-service-why)